# How do I add two :before elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to make web site with minimal `HTML` markup for presentation.
Having the following `HTML` tag:

```
<div class="title">I'm a title!</div>
```

I need to add two elements before it using `CSS`, 1 for background and 1 for shadow.
Something like:

```
.title
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.title:before
{
    display: block;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.title:before
{
    display :block;
    background-color: #111111;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5px -5px -5px 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

doesn't work because the second `.title:before` overrides the first.
I cant add the background to the element because I need it to have opacity.
Is there any way to do this without adding additional markup? And if the answer is somehow not using two `:before` elements is there any way to specify more then one?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you'd apply ***n*** elements, but for only two (and especially here) it seems to me you could just use `:after` for the second element...

Comment: I know, but I was kind of hoping to get solution that would fit for n elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Have you tried something like `.title:before:before`? Maybe this helps... Not able to test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use backgroungd gradient image instead

you call then Something like

```
background : url("../images/image_path.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Comment: I'm trying to build a site without "hacks" like this one.

Comment: I wouldn't say using background-image is a hack :-)

Comment: solid color background image isn't hack? and what about transparent 1 pixel images for sizing? its the same.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you cant just use...

```
.title
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
.title:before
{
    display :block;
    background-color: #111111;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 5px -5px -5px 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: because i need opacity on the background but not on text

Comment: Im confused. Do you mean transparency (rather than opacity) ?

Comment: I don't know what's the term.
I mean it will blent with the background.

Answer (score 0):

Two `before`s will be only in future. No one browser supports it now.

Here specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-content-20030514/#nesting

And second `before` will be working like `div::before::before` or `div::before(2)`